# Redbean: How does one get last inserted id of owned Bean?

Tags: orm, redbean

I use RedBeanPHP 3.5.1 for ORM in my MVP project (powered by Nette FW).

I need to get ID of the last inserted element, that is owned by element from another table. Below you can find method representing functionality which I just described:

```
public function createSite($userId, $siteName, $feedUrl, $reloadTime, $reloadRate){
    $site = R::dispense('site');
    $site->user_id = $userId;
    $site->name = $siteName;
    $site->feed = $feedUrl;
    $site->reload_time = $reloadTime;
    $site->reload_rate = $reloadRate;

    $user = R::load('user', $userId);
    $user->ownSite[] = $site;
    $id = R::store($user);

    return $id; 
}
```

Now I would assume that line

```
$id = R::store($user);
```

would store **site ID** into `$id` variable since it is owned by already existing user. Instead of that it fills variable with user ID that I have no further use for.

So my question is: **How do I get last inserted ID of owned bean that was just created by calling `R::store()` method on parent (just loaded) bean?** Is there an implementation on this in RedBean or do I have to do this manually?

I browsed every corner of RedBeanPHP project web but so far no luck.

Thanks for possible suggestions, guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using common sense I finally figured out how to solve this elegantly and since no one answered my question so far let my just do that myself.

Since `R::store($user)` is capable of storing both `$user` and `$site`, there is misleadingly no need to store `$site` object manually.

But if you need to get last inserted id of owned bean, there is really no harm in doing so. By **storing `$site` object** framework will do the exact same thing and on top of that **it returns resired id**.

So the correct method implementation looks like this:

```
public function createSite($userId, $siteName, $feedUrl, $reloadTime, $reloadRate){
    $site = R::dispense('site');
    $site->user_id = $userId;
    $site->name = $siteName;
    $site->feed = $feedUrl;
    $site->reload_time = $reloadTime;
    $site->reload_rate = $reloadRate;

    $user = R::load('user', $userId);
    $user->ownSite[] = $site;

    $id = R::store($site);
    R::store($user);

    return $id;
}
```

So in conclusion, **hats off to RedBeanPHP** ORM FW and I sincerely hope this helps people with similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called R::findLast('...')

```
$last_record = R::findLast('...');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would have been a correct answer 7 years ago but at least now there is no need to do any kind of extra work:

```
$shop = R::dispense( 'shop' );
$shop->name = 'Antiques';
$vase = R::dispense( 'product' );
$vase->price = 25;
$shop->ownProductList[] = $vase
R::store( $shop );
echo $vase->$id; // <-- yes, id which was created by database is present here
```